# Deserialize JSON with metadata in C# using json.net/RestSharp

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp

I am attempting to create a dataSet containing information from a JSON file I am receiving from an API.

I keep getting a JsonSerializationException as "Unexpected JSON token when reading..." occurs. The unexpected token is some metadata ("paging" etc) I can't seem to get rid of. Is there a way to either ignore the metadata or not even receive it in the first place?

**Json file:**

```
 {
  "paging": {
    "size": 8
  },
  "data": {
    "devices": [
      {
        "hostName": "x",
        "networkAddress": "x",
        "bestState": "Down",
        "worstState": "Down",
        "name": "x",
        "id": "1301"
      },
      {
        "hostName": "x",
        "networkAddress": "x",
        "bestState": "Down",
        "worstState": "Down",
        "name": "x",
        "id": "1299"
      },
      {
        "hostName": "x",
        "networkAddress": "x",
        "bestState": "Down",
        "worstState": "Down",
        "name": "x",
        "id": "1296"
      },
      {
        "hostName": "x",
        "networkAddress": "x",
        "bestState": "Down",
        "worstState": "Down",
        "name": "x",
        "id": "1291"
      },
      {
        "hostName": "x",
        "networkAddress": "x",
        "bestState": "Down",
        "worstState": "Down",
        "name": "x",
        "id": "1261"
      },
      {
        "hostName": "x",
        "networkAddress": "x",
        "bestState": "Down",
        "worstState": "Down",
        "name": "x",
        "id": "1249"
      },
      {
        "hostName": "x",
        "networkAddress": "x",
        "bestState": "Up",
        "worstState": "Down",
        "name": "x",
        "id": "157"
      },
      {
        "hostName": "x",
        "networkAddress": "x",
        "bestState": "Up",
        "worstState": "Down",
        "name": "x",
        "id": "205"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**My code**

```
             //Following block (2) taken from Postman, looks for device down group using bearer token retreived from block (1)
            var client2 = new RestClient("x");
            client2.Timeout = -1;
            var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request2.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + bearer.access_token);
            IRestResponse response2 = client2.Execute(request2);
            textBox1.Text = response2.Content;
            //end of block (2)

            //Deserialize dataset from downDevices
            DataSet dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(response2.Content);
            DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables["devices"];
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(row["name"] + " - " + row["networkAddress"]);

            }
```

The only potential solution I have found but not been able to try thus far is in the Newtonsoft documentation: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMetadataPropertyHandling.htm
However, I am not sure if there is a way to use this object in conjunction with the dataSet.

```
            object o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response2.Content, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,

                MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead //maybe use ignore?
            });
            //end of test Object
```

I apologize if this is a fairly basic/stupid question or seems repeated, I have gone through as many similar questions as possible and tried some potential solutions but to no avail. I further apologize if any of my terminology is weird/wrong, I am brand new to C# and API's as a whole.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add a breakpoint and see what is being returned for response2.content. Make sure it's valid JSON

Comment: @LinkedListT What I have entered in above for "Json File:" is precisely what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you are trying to deserialize. `DataTable`deserialization would work if you had to deserialize only the `Devices` object. But with the addition of `Paging` (not a valid dataset) and `Data` objs, you need to write a custom class to deserialize this obj and point it to the `DataTable`. Something like this:

```
public static void Deserialize()
    {
      string response2 = "{ \"paging\": { \"size\": 8 }, \"data\": { \"devices\": [ { \"hostName\": \"x\", \"networkAddress\": \"x\", \"bestState\": \"Down\", \"worstState\": \"Down\", \"name\": \"x\", \"id\": \"1301\" }] } } ";
      var dataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Target>(response2);
      Console.WriteLine(dataSet);

      DataTable dataTable = dataSet.data.devices;
      Console.WriteLine(dataTable);

      foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(row["hostname"]+" :name");
      }         
    }
}
class Target
{
    public object paging{get;set;}
    public Device data{get;set;}
}

class Device
{
    public DataTable devices {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is invalid: `"networkAddress": "x,`, there is a missing `"` in an object with `id` **1299**

Comment: Hey, that was my bad I apologize, I accidentally deleted it when I was censoring out some IP's and site addresses.

Comment: I think it should be considered as comment, not the answer